# PHP not running bat file command

Tags: php, ajax, windows, batch-file

I have setup a website on Windows Server 2012 R2, installed IIS (8?), installed PHP through Microsoft Web Platform Installer (PHP 7). I've created a test batch file with the contents:

```
echo before
md test
echo after
```

I have an AJAX POST run my PHP file which contains:

```
<?php

system("cmd /c test.bat");
```

I have the data from the AJAX request output to the console, and I get the before, I get the md command, but then it stops.

**I've tried:**

1. Giving IIS_IUSRS permission to the bat file
2. Different combinations of `system()` and `exec()`
3. Editing Handler Mappings for PHP to allow "Execute"
4. Just running the command through PHP, and I just get blank

None of that has worked.

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

**Update:**

I was able to use this to create a folder in the C: drive, however I'm not able to create a folder in the website directory.

Comment: Whats the error log give. My guess it cant find the file.

Comment: I checked the error log for PHP and there's nothing in there related to this, and Chrome console outputs the commands that the bat file is running, but stops at "md test" because it fails.

Comment: Chrome is the browser. How are you getting messages in the browser? I would assume your running the on the server and the browser would know nothing.

Comment: The AJAX on success will output the data into the console.

Comment: Ok, I would think it's a permission problem then. It's running in some directory. change to the directory you want to make the test dir in. Make sure the user that the webserver is running under has write access to.